# Rails 4: Rendering JSON object (from AJAX response) into view

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Rails 4 and I'm quite new to JSON objects.

I have a controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

 def select_users

   @users = User.all
   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js {} 
     format.json { 
        render json: {:users => @users}
     } 
   end
 end
end
```

And a javascript users.js:

```
$.ajax({
    url:  "/users/select_users",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        prezzario: ui.item.value
    },
    success: function(data) { 
        $('#usersList').append(data.users);
    }
});
```

Now I want to render this collection of users in a div, but I don't know how. In the data response I have in the console the correct data, with an object like this:

```
{"users":[{"_id":{"$oid":"536cf7b6b8dd181f4b7acf9f"},"children":[{"$oid":"536cf7b6b8dd181f4b7acfa0"},{"$oid":"536cf7b7b8dd181f4b7acfd1"}],"description":"Some description.","name":"My name","user_id":"1"},{...........}]}
```

I have a partial /users/_users.html.erb with classic users.each and prints of all properties.
If I try

```
$('#usersList').append("<%= render 'users', :locals{ :users => "+data.users+"} %>");
```

I find in the div `#usersList  <%= render 'users', :locals{ :users => undefined }%>`

I want to create a partial template and use it to render users. How can I do this?

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 solutions (that i can think of):

1. Your controller can render HTML on the backend that you append to your js, like

   ```
    class UsersController < ApplicationController

      def select_users
        @users = User.all
        render "view", :users => @users
      end
   ```

   and

   ```
    success: function(data) {
      $('#usersList').append(data);
    }
   ```
2. You can use something like Moustache or Handlebars. Never used it, so I can't do a proper example. Sorry.
3. You can render the html in side the success code like

   ```
    success: function(data){
      data.users.forEach(function(user){
        $user_html = $("<div class='user'>" + user.name + "<!-- etc --!/></div>");
        $('#usersList').append($user_html);
      });
    });
   ```

Comment: Thank you. Now as ajax response I have an html page, but I have two problem:

Comment: Thank you. Now as ajax response I have an html page, but I have two problems: 1. $('#usersList').append(data); don't produce any result. 2. users are rendered in a complete view with header footer, while I want to render only in a partial and then add this partial to the page from which the ajax call has been performed.

Comment: I resolved using in the ajax call dataType 'html' and in the controller render partial: 'users' . Thanks for help!

Comment: No problem! Glad i could help.

If you want to render a full view, you can do

    render "view", :layout => false

and it will render the view w.o all the layout stuff.

Answer (score 1):

You have to `$.parseJSON(data);` first.

Like

```
 $.ajax({
    url:  "/users/select_users",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
       prezzario: ui.item.value
    },
    success: function(data) { 
       var r = $.parseJSON(data);
       console.log(r.users)//This is where Your users are
    }
});
```